# Logarithmic scale use cases

Tags: data-visualization

Is it fine to use logarithmic scale with bar charts? (I guess I depends on a specific case, like using the logarithmic scale anywhere else). I have done so in a [Power BI report](https://app.powerbi.com/groups/89eac521-7fb9-4f0f-93fe-0500bb45135f/reports/0de16804-926d-48ac-b647-b4d8c02daecf/ReportSection0a260a75b9bc81a9030b?experience=power-bi) when comparing each store's number of products by category. I wanted the interactive visual to accurately display the difference between stores in the mentioned matter, at a glance. Especially that one store just has way more ordered products than the others. What would you do in my position? I would appreciate your advice on the matter, you can give me some feedback on the whole report too.

[image: Baldwin Bikes when using logarithmic scale]
[image: Rowlett Bikes when using logarithmic scale]

[image: Baldwin Bikes when not using logarithmic scale]
[image: Rowlett Bikes when not using logarithmic scale]

Comment: It’s fine, but it may be hard for people (especially non technical people) to grok what the plot is showing

Comment: I am OK with log scales, but probably you should use the same scaling for all of the graphs. Don't make people do the work of switching. (Are the summaries on the right so much more important than the graphs their prominence and the near invisibility of the graph labels makes sense?)

Comment: To @michaellew's point, why are you switching from log to frequency scales in the first place? Otherwise, log scale bar charts are *fine*.

Comment: Interesting question with well-designed graphics. The lower two bar charts are perfectly well-readable. So, I would stick to a linear representation of the numbers. (BTW, your report is not accessible without logging in.)

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend on balance against logarithmic scales for bar charts. The best reason for that is that there is a constructive alternative, using logarithmic scales and (Cleveland) dot charts.

The motivation for a bar chart is that bar lengths or heights convey magnitude proportionally. You are bending that principle once you use any nonlinear scale. Are you breaking it?

- Some considerations are social or psychological, as **many not so technical readers will find logarithmic scales confusing  or obscure, while some more technical readers might be disposed to think using logarithmic scale for bar charts as at least inappropriate if not wrong**. There may be an age or generation effect here: teaching logarithms as a way to do messy calculations became obsolete about 50 years ago when cheap calculators became available. People who studied logarithms briefly in high school or college may not remember the idea well later in a professional career. Conversely, it is interesting that (e.g.) *The Economist* uses logarithmic scale routinely without feeling the need to explain much. The Covid pandemic meant that logarithmic scales were often used in newspaper or television reports.
- Clearly **you can't show zero on a logarithmic scale, so what does the base of your bars represent?** A value of 1 for which the logarithm is zero? But in principle at least you should want to be able to show occurrences of just 1 product clearly and explicitly. Any such occurrences should not be implicit as a bar with length zero. This may not bite hard with your data, but it could bite hard for other readers of this thread tempted to draw bar charts on logarithmic scale: if their bars represented measured magnitudes and some magnitudes are positive but at or below 1, what should they do?
- If you do decide to use logarithmic scale, **it needs more vigorous flagging than just being implied by your tick labels**. Consider some prominent text declaration in your display.
- Granted that wanting to show very big amounts or counts and much smaller values with equal clarity is the motive for wanting a logarithmic scale at all, **a constructive alternative is a (Cleveland) dot chart using logarithmic scale and any marker or point symbol of your choice**. This is easier to sell - to yourself as well as your readership - as based on the principle that dot or marker position conveys magnitude. Positive values of 1 or less can also be shown explicitly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_plot_(statistics) gives a simple introduction. Otherwise Google or read the documentation of your software for how to do it.
- In passing, I note other solutions: **you could use other nonlinear scales, notably square root, cube root, logarithm after adding 1, or asinh (inverse hyperbolic sine)**. These all have the small virtue that zeros map to zeros and they can be extended or generalized to cope with negative values too. Such transformations can be explained to technical readers, but may still meet resistance or even hostility as being  unfamiliar or arbitrary. Some statistically minded people regard some as utterly unacceptable, *ad hoc* in the worst sense, and even dangerous.